# Is the univalence of the canonical family over a universe small?

Tags: lo.logic, homotopy-type-theory

Working in Martin-Löf intensional type theory, $\mathsf{ITT}$, with a universe $U$ within the theory closed under all the usual constructors, the univalence of the canonical family $\mathsf{EI}$ over $U$ can (via the Curry-Howard correspondence)  be regarded as a type $\mathsf{isUnivalent}(U)$.

> Is $\mathsf{isUnivalent}(U)$ a term of type $U$?

Comment: I though it was $\mathsf{El}$ and not $\mathsf{EI}$. It stands for "elements".

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the question. Is $\mathsf{isUnivalent}$ some sort of a type family? How is it defined? If you write out what $\mathsf{isUnivalent}(U)$ means, I think you will see that it mentions $U$, and therefore will not be an element of $U$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me first try to make the question precise. Suppose $U$ is a universe. The statement "$U$ is univalent" which you are asking about is
$$\prod_{A,B : U} \mathsf{isEquiv}(\mathsf{idtoeq}_{A,B}) \tag{1}$$
where
$$\mathsf{idtoeq}_{A,B} : \mathsf{Id}_U(A,B) \to \mathsf{Equiv}(\mathsf{El}(A), \mathsf{El}(B))$$
is the canonical map that turns paths in the universe $U$ to equivalences between the corresponding types, and $\mathsf{isEquiv}(f)$ is the statement that $f$ is an equivalence. Now, $\mathsf{isEquiv}(f)$ lives in the same universe as $f$, and so $\mathsf{isEquiv}(\mathsf{idtoeq}_{A,B})$ lives in $U$. Thus the product (1) is a product over $U$ of types in $U$. This means that it is *not* an element of $U$, unless $U$ is *impredicative*, i.e., closed under prdoucts over $U$.

The question the is whether we can have an impredicative univalent universe. I do not know the answer.

Comment: If we don't ask $U$ to be closed under type-formers like coproducts, then I think the universe of propositions in a topos is impredicative and univalent.

Comment: For $A,B: U$, is $\mathsf{isEquiv}(\mathsf{idtoeq_{A,B}})$ a mere proposition?

Comment: Yes, it's a mere proposition. That is an important fact to know. The HoTT book discusses it at length in the section on equivalences.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: We don’t need *U* itself to be impredicative (which as you know is very strong, and inconsistent with lots of other nice principles and closure conditions on *U*).  It’s enough to have *isEquiv* take values in an impredicative subuniverse of *U*, which is a much weaker condition.  E.g. if we have a universe Ω of all propositions — as in e.g. the simplicial set model — then this is impredicative as Mike says, so for any universe *U* containing Ω (e.g. Voevodsky’s simplicial universe), we can express “*U* is univalent” as a type in *U*.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine aye